# Draw a table with cells of different sizes and colours

Tags: tables

I would like to draw a table like the following:

[image]

I had thought about making the border of the outer cells transparent, but I don't know how to set the size of a single cell to be different (also how to set the dots ". . . ." horizontally and vertically). Does anyone know of a simple way to do this? Also, how could I make cell [2, 2] have a different coloured border?

**Solution used (based on answers):**

```
\begin{NiceTabular}{cccc}[margin,hvlines,first-row,first-col]
      & Recurso 1 & Recurso 2 & \hspace{0.7cm} . . . \hspace{0.7cm} & Recurso $n$ \\
    Individuo 1 &  &  & & \\
    Individuo 2 &  & \Block[draw=blue,line-width=1pt]{1-1}{~} & & \\ 
    $$\vdots$$ &  &  &  & \\
    Individuo $m$ &  &  &  & \\
\end{NiceTabular}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It would be very helpful if you provided the code that shows what you have tried.

This being said, it is easy to do that with `nicematrix`. So easy that it is quicker to just paste the code than to go through a conversation why it is helpful to show the code attempts (even though this is really helpful...).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\begin{document}
\begin{NiceTabular}{ccp{2.5cm}c}[margin,hvlines,first-row,first-col]
      & Recurso 1 & Recurso 2 & \Cdots & Recurso $n$ \\
    Individuo 1 &  &  & & \\
    Individuo 2 &  & \Block[draw=blue,line-width=1pt]{1-1}{~} & & \\
    \Vdots &  &  &  & \\
    Individuo $m$ &  &  &  & \\
\end{NiceTabular}    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, that was a huge mistake, sorry for that. I updated the question with the solution I'm using. Last question, do you know how could I center the dots? Thanks in advance.